# Is there a readily available tool for profiling thread usage?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that is leaving orphaned threads in a way that is not readily apparent. I would like to profile thread use (creation, disposal) over the course of a period of time.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Doesn't the Visual Studio Thread window show you this?

Comment: Orphaning a thread is good. Disposing is not necessary or desired,